# LINQ-to-SQL - Group By

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ-to-SQL code

```
var customerList = from cm in dc.ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns
                   join tm in dc.ConsignmentTripBreakdowns on new { Depot = cm.Depot, TripNumber = cm.TripNumber, TripDate = cm.TripDate } equals new { Depot = tm.Depot, TripNumber = tm.TripNumber, TripDate = tm.TripDate }
                   join sl in dc.SageAccounts on new { LegacyID = cm.Customer, Customer = true } equals new { LegacyID = sl.LegacyID, Customer = sl.Customer }
                   join ss in dc.SageAccounts on sl.ParentAccount equals ss.ID
                   where (tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange1.FromDate && tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange1.ToDate) || (dateRange2.FromDate != null && (tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange2.FromDate && tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange2.ToDate))
                   where tm.Depot == depotLetter
                   group cm by new { ss.Name, ss.ID } into cmg
                   select new
                   {
                       CustomerID = cmg.Key.ID,
                       CustomerName = cmg.Key.Name,
                       Sales1 = cmg.Where(a => a.DeliveryDate >= dateRange1.FromDate && a.DeliveryDate <= dateRange1.ToDate).Sum(a => a.TripSalesTotal),
                       Sales2 = dateRange2.FromDate != null ? tmg.Where(a => a.DeliveryDate >= dateRange2.FromDate && a.DeliveryDate <= dateRange2.ToDate).Sum(a => a.TripSalesTotal) : 0.00m
                   };
```

The problem I have is that the 'DeliveryDate' from 'tm' is not in the scope of the query when I select. Any ideas how I can get this value in my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another anonymous type

```
 group new { cm, tm } by new { ss.Name, ss.ID } into cmg
```

so your query would look like this:

```
var customerList = from cm in dc.ConsignmentMarginBreakdowns
                   join tm in dc.ConsignmentTripBreakdowns on new { Depot = cm.Depot, TripNumber = cm.TripNumber, TripDate = cm.TripDate } equals new { Depot = tm.Depot, TripNumber = tm.TripNumber, TripDate = tm.TripDate }
                   join sl in dc.SageAccounts on new { LegacyID = cm.Customer, Customer = true } equals new { LegacyID = sl.LegacyID, Customer = sl.Customer }
                   join ss in dc.SageAccounts on sl.ParentAccount equals ss.ID
                   where (tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange1.FromDate && tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange1.ToDate) || (dateRange2.FromDate != null && (tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange2.FromDate && tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange2.ToDate))
                   where tm.Depot == depotLetter
                   group new { cm, tm } by new { ss.Name, ss.ID } into cmg
                   select new
                   {
                       CustomerID = cmg.Key.ID,
                       CustomerName = cmg.Key.Name,
                       Sales1 = cmg.Where(a => a.tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange1.FromDate && a.tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange1.ToDate).Sum(a => a.cm.TripSalesTotal),
                       Sales2 = dateRange2.FromDate != null ? tmg.Where(a => a.tm.DeliveryDate >= dateRange2.FromDate && a.tm.DeliveryDate <= dateRange2.ToDate).Sum(a => a.cm.TripSalesTotal) : 0.00m
                   };
```